# Standard format for Reporting

Tags: manual-testing, standards

Is there any standard format for reports i.e. order of the columns in the reports? For example, we have usually ID's, Names, Dates. Addresses, Amount etc in the reports. Is there any standard for the order of these columns? Because i have to standardized and test a huge portal containing these kind of similar reports.

Comment: About which report you are talking about? Bug Report?

Comment: Simple Reports we extract from the databases into excel sheets. is there any format for the order of these columns in reports?

Comment: No then it does not require any change, just maintain column sequence same as you stored in database.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For users, it is preferable that first few columns are in the sort order.

Another good heuristics is to group short fields and related fields, and put important/required fields to left, and optional/unimportant fields to the right.

Comment: it means there are only heuristics, not standards. Thank you !  :)